# Loading registered dll from python

Tags: .net, python, windows, dll

I have registered the xceedzip.dll (admin cmd run -> regsvr32 xceedzip.dll)
I would like to access the .net classes inside this dll from python.

In particular, I need to uncompress a continuous data stream from a multicast feed. The data comes in a xceedzip compressed form, and require the uncompress method to be executed on the data to unpackage it. for reference: http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedSco/

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be appreciated. This won't have a 1-step ready ctypes solution to my understanding. This is because the Uncompress method lives in a class of a .net namespace.

I am informed that the win32com library might be able to achieve this, but would like some guidance before i put my nose to that grindstone.

Thanks,

Comment: ... Python already supports bzip2 and DEFLATE natively...

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, this is data coming from an exchange - and the API doc specifically mentions "All messages sent by or received from the system should be compressed or uncompressed using xceed zip version 4.2." I suppose uncompressing might not be the issue, but if i were to talk back to the exchange would it not be imperative that i be following their prescribed methodology ?

Comment: You must follow the data format. I'm fairly certain that it won't be able to tell *what* generated it so long as it's generated properly.

Comment: hmm alright, will look into this backdooring. thank you

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams                                                        on trying with the bz2 module, i get IOError: invalid data stream. on trying with the zlib library i get error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check. any suggestions ? i spoke to a guy from the other end, and he just parroted that i need to use the .net xceedzip.dll uncompress method. so coming back to my original quesion, what's the best way of doing this from python ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the trial for it, and this seems to work:

```
import win32com.client
x=win32com.client.Dispatch('Xceed.StreamingCompression')
compressed = x.Compress(buffer('bork bork bork aaaaa bbbbbbbb'), True)
decompressed = x.Decompress(compressed, True)
print decompressed
```